# Any vs Anyone - The difference

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

There seems to be a difference between "**any**" and "**anyone**" but I can't feel it.

- Behold ye, for if any linger without a hope in the shadows, blind they shall become and not them anymore.

Why not **anyone**?

Comment: For one thing, because this is not the Queen's English, but the King's — meaning King James I, in point of fact, from the early 17th century. It's at least biblical in period and style, if not verbatim text. Addendum: are you sure you didn't make this up?

Comment: Either one could be considered correct, but @Robusto brings up an excellent point. Verily, verily, behold ye, if any sentence commenceth with "behold ye," be not surprised if the remainder sounds antiquated as well. Oh, and -1 for [not citing the context](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source). You should know better by now.

Comment: @Robusto This is from the modded game Diablo, the name of the mod I don't remember. Fans added a few dialogues to the Halls of the blind quest.

Comment: OK, so it's not **actually** old but it's stylized to be old... no one actually talks like this outside of a renaissance festival.

Comment: "and not them anymore" is ungrammatical, FWIW.

Comment: @TRomano Yeh, it shpuld be "themselves"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any is plural in this instant.  It is referring to an anonymous plural.  Anyone is singular.  The reason why it isn't anyone is because the writer/speaker is likely addressing more than one person.  As far as I know, this type of sentence is common when addressing a gathering, such as a wedding.